# Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, date, ibatis

I am using ibatis and C#. i get a result from a select query that has CreatedDate as one of the field. The Datatype of CreatedDate in Mysql is Date. I assign the result set of the select query to a Ilist< DeliveryClass>.

Here the DeliveryClass CreatedDate as DateTime. When i run the application, i get  **Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime**. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

```
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; database=luttop; user=root; password=1234; pooling = false; convert zero datetime=True");
```

Adding `convert zero datetime=True` to the connection string will automatically convert `0000-00-00` Date values to `DateTime.MinValue()`.

that's SOLVED

Comment: This is better solution than chosen.

Comment: This one worked fine for me, after updating the connection string in the appSettings.json file. Thank you @Klors.

Answer (score 13):

Adding "convert zero datetime=True" to the connection string solved my problem.

```
<connectionStrings>   <add name="MyContext" connectionString="Datasource=localhost;Database=MyAppDb;Uid=root;Pwd=root;CHARSET=utf8;convert zero datetime=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" /> </connectionStrings>
```

Regards
PS

Answer (score 6):

I solved my problem by setting the column's default value as `null` data rather than using `0000-00-00 00:00:00`:

```
update table set date = null
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem in the format, actually mysql have a different format (yyyy-mm-dd) for the date/time data type and to solve this problem use the mysql connector library  for .net from here 
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ 
it will give other data type for the date/time called MysqlDateTime

or you can format the date/time data in your sql statement using DATE_FORMAT(date,format) 
you can get more details from here 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

but i don't recommend this because you will loose the power of date/time data type (for example you can't compare) because now you will convert it to string but i think it will be useful in the reports

Comment: On updating the connector to the latest didn't solve my problem

Comment: the connector it self will not solve your problem it depends how you are retrieving your data ?? for example i used my generation doodads template i override the retrieving property for the datetime (reading the value from the datatable => convert it from mysqldatetime to .net datetime) 
how u retrieve your data ?

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values. Formats come into play only when parsing text containing date literals. Which *shouldn't* be used, as they introduce conversion errors and the possibility of SQL injection

Answer (score 2):

It could be outside the range of a DateTime object.  I've seen that a couple of times.  Try changing the sql to return the current date instead of your column and see if it comes through ok.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the simple change with the connection string you added for MySql database. **i.e** **CONVERT ZERO DATETIME = TRUE**

```
<add name="NAMEOFYOURCONNECTIONSTRING" connectionString="server's HOSTNAMEorIP(i.e Localhost or IP address);user id=USER_ID(i.e User ID for login Database);Pwd=PASSWORD(i.e User Password for login Database);persistsecurityinfo=True;database=NAMEOFDATABASE;Convert Zero Datetime=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Please elaborate properly.

Comment: @DarpanSanghavi Hope you can now understand easily.

Answer (score 1):

Have two possibilities.

1 ->
Cast all of the DateTimes '0000-00-00' to NULL.

This include in 'SELECT' querys. Example :
(if any row returned has a DateTime equals a '0000-00-00', if not, it's not necessary.)

```
 SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(DATEZERO,'%Y-%m-%d') DATEZERO ## CAST TO STRING
    FROM TABLE;
```

2 -> Add param in sql connection:

```
"convert zero datetime=True"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
SELECT 
    IF(tb.Date1 = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', NULL, tb.Date1) AS ValidDate
FROM MyTable AS tb
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing who works too is changing your reader action.
I was having this problem when I wrote

```
string myvar = reader.GetString(0);
```

Then I used to write this

```
object myvar = reader.GetValue(0);
```

And no more error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me when a date column in my table had been set to 0 rather than null - there was a bug in my code that.

Looking at the table I could see that the field had been set to a date of 000-00-00 - once I had reset the offending field to null the issue went away.