# Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime

Tags: .net, asp.net, mysql, asp.net-3.5

I get this error:

> Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime

while I am trying to fetch the data from a MySQL database.
I have the **date** datatype in my MySQL database. But while retrieving it into my datatable, it get the error above.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934844/unable-to-convert-mysql-date-time-value-to-system-datetime)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If I google for "Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime" I see numerous references to a problem accessing MySQL from Visual Studio. Is that your context?

One solution suggested is:

> This is not a bug but expected
>   behavior. Please check manual under
>   connect options and set "Allow Zero
>   Datetime" to true, as on attached
>   pictures, and the error will go away.

Reference: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26054

Comment: I suggest not to use '0000-00-00 00:00:00' as your data in date/time columns. Rather use a real date values in your data - if you are using .net. However, MySQL can handle any dates. You should scan through all your date/time values.

Answer (score 232):

You must add `Convert Zero Datetime=True` to your connection string, for example:

```
server=localhost;User Id=root;password=mautauaja;Persist Security Info=True;database=test;Convert Zero Datetime=True
```

Comment: Thanks! FYI: This goes on the MySQL connection string - not the SQL Server connection string.

Comment: saved my time. Worked like a charm

Comment: +1 - Perfect! I had zero datetimes because when the column wasn't fill write on table MySQL the zero datetime. I prefer change it from now for 0970-01-01.Thanks you so much

Answer (score 23):

i added both `Convert Zero Datetime=True` & `Allow Zero Datetime=True` and it works fine

Answer (score 3):

Pull the datetime value down as a string and do a `DateTime.ParseExact(value, "ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy", culture, styles);` You would just need to set the date format up for the date you are returning from the database. Most likely it's `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. At least is is for me.

Check here more info on the [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same problem, and get the columns name and its types. Then cast(col_Name as Char) from table name. From this way i get the problem as '0000-00-00 00:00:00' then I Update as valid date and time the error gets away for my case.

Answer (score 2):

Let MySql convert your unix timestamp to string. Use the mysql function FROM_UNIXTIME( 113283901 )

Answer (score 1):

Rather than changing the connection string, you can use the `IsValidDateTime` property of the `MySqlDateTime` object to help you determine if you can cast the object as a `DateTime`.

I had a scenario where I was trying to load data from an "UpdateTime" column that was only explicitly set when there was an update to the row (as opposed to the InsertedTime which was always set). For this case, I used the `MySqlDataReader.GetMySqlDateTime` method like so:

```
using (MySqlDataReader reader = await MySqlHelper.ExecuteReaderAsync(...))
{
    if (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        DateTime? updateTime = reader.GetMySqlDateTime("UpdateTime").IsValidDateTime ? (DateTime?)reader["UpdateTime"] : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a Stimulsoft report add this parameter to the connection string
(right click on datasource->edit)

```
Convert Zero Datetime=True;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're using EF edmx with MySql, please review the Precision attribute in the entitytype.

```
<EntityType Name="table">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
  </Key>
  <Property Name="Id" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
  <Property Name="date_field" Type="datetime" Precision="0" Nullable="false" />
</EntityType>
```

If you made changes in the datetime field, it could be possible you're missing this attribute in the property.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the application fully compatible with the date and time that is used by MySql. When the application runs at runtime provide this code.
First Go to the Application Events.
In the list of tools

1. Go to the project
2. Project Properties
3. Select the Application tab
4. View Application Events

This will open a new file. This file contains code used at the start of the application.

Write this code in that new file:

```
 Partial Friend Class MyApplication

    Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
        My.Application.ChangeCulture("en")
        My.Application.ChangeUICulture("en")
        My.Application.Culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        My.Application.Culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        My.Application.Culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss"
        My.Application.Culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss"
    End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

if **"allow zero datetime=true"** is not working then use the following sollutions:-

Add this to your connection string:  **"allow zero datetime=no"** - that made the type cast work perfectly.