# Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime.Couldn't store 0/0/0000 0:00:00 value?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datetime, null

```
Me.TreatmentsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.UserDataSet1.treatments)
```

This line  is producing error:

```
Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime. Couldn't store <0/0/0000 0:00:00> in TreatmentDateEdited Column.  Expected type is DateTime.
```

`TreatmentDateEdited` column is `DateTime` column that unfortunately contains some `NULL` values.
I know that there is a problem in Dataset to convert `NULL` date to anything else, thus producing me this error.

1. in connection string I have already added:  `AllowZeroDateTime=True` but that does not help
2. Now from the above error msg I see that `NULL` value is already converted to `0/0/0000 0:00:00` but it cant store it in date field.

What date format should I use here in order to have Tableadapter operational ?

**EDIT**: I found possible problem here:
MySQL column of type DateTime doesn't allow me to enter date in any format I tried. I foudn that the default date format is `1000-01-01 00:00:00` but it wont accept that ! this is the error

> Invalid value for cell (row 3, column 8).
>   The changed value in this cell was not recognized as valid..Net Framework Data Type: MySqlDateTime
>   Error Message: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime'.

So if I cant write date in date column manually neither TableAdapter will do. Any ideas ?

EDIT2: @GoroundoVipa
The thing is I dont loop dataset but use it as datasource in form controls.
Here are 2 other things I have noticed:
1. When using VisualStudio ServerExplorer to access database I am not able to enter new data in datetime field (producing above error)
2. When I access DB through MySQL workbench I got another error:
"Error: `DB`.`TABLE`: table data is not editable because there is no primary key defined for the table"
Server:  MySQL
Version: 5.1.73

How on earth I can not edit table row if it doesn't have PK. It was never required !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754822/unable-to-convert-mysql-date-time-value-to-system-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL NULL Value for Date is `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`, You won't be able to insert a Date in `0000-00-00 00:00:00.000`

I've Experience it lately, my solution for that is store the NULL value and replace it when displaying in DataGridView or Etc...

Sample:

```
if DataGridView1.Rows(e.Index).Cells(10).Value.ToString = "1900-01-01 00:00:00.000" Then

DataGridView1.Rows(e.Index).Cells(10).Value = ""

End If
```