# VB.NET how to convert a string into time

Tags: vb.net

Ive been having some trouble with this for a while. I want to be able to retrieve values of time stored in my database (as type time).
I've tried:

```
reader.getDateTime("open_hours")
```

I just get an error.
I've also tried converting the string into time but i can only convert it into datetime, meaning that i have the date as well as the time.
How can i get just the time (in 24 hour format)?

Comment: the `GetDateTime` function already returns a DateTime object, so *Mission Accomplished*.  No idea what `I just get an error` means

Comment: The error is 'Unable to convert MYSQL date/time value to system.datetime'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5754822/1070452

Comment: I tired adding Convert Zero Datetime=True to my connection string but now all iget from the reader is 00:00:00

Answer (score 3):

you can use this [link](http://net-informations.com/q/faq/stringdate.html)

for example:-

```
Dim strTime As String = "3:00 PM"

' Convert to datetime

Dim dtTime As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(strTime)
' Display in 24hr format

Response.Write(dtTime.ToString("HH:mm"))
```

example2:-

```
string militaryTime;
string originalTime = "3:11 PM";
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParse(originalTime, out dt))
    militaryTime = dt.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Comment: The thing is, is need the it as a datetime, not a string, so that i can compare times.

Comment: nice one, this is what i've been looking for