# c# Select sql database data using datetimepicker set with date range

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I am trying to make c# program, where I have to make a database report to be previewed at the datagridview. Data will be selected using the datetimepicker. I have written the code, it works but then if the date selected is of different months. No records appear

```
void FilterDBbtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
    
        conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
        
        string data = "SELECT `Date`, `Process`, `Actual`, `Target` FROM `database` WHERE `Date` BETWEEN '"+this.fromDatePicker.Value+"' AND  '"+this.toDatePicker.Value+"' order by `Date` desc";
        

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(data, conn);
        
        
        cmd.Connection.Open();
            
        try
        {
            
          MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
          sda.SelectCommand = cmd;          
          DataSet dt = new DataSet();
          sda.Fill(dt);
          BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
          bsource.DataSource = dt;
          mondeDataTable.DataSource = dt.Tables[0];
          sda.Update(dt);
        
        }
        
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        
        
        cmd.Connection.Close();
}
```

please help me check my code and tell me what might be wrong or missing.

Comment: Check what is sql injection, also use debug and see why nothing happens..You should dispose your MySqlDataAdapter too.

Comment: what is your `Date` format and  `fromDatePicker.Value` format. if they are different like **'2016-10-13 00:00:00.000'** and **'2013-10-13 09:50:00.000'**, query may return 0 rows.

Comment: I have set it to be just the date, and no time included.

Comment: debug your code and run your query variable result in Db

Comment: I did also try and same thing happens, no data appears whenever I write a different month. Is there any code for selecting different months? Is between doesn't work with it?

Comment: the date format is really my problem.. How will I convert the sql date/time to system.time

Answer (score 0):

Use profiler to check the query that hits the DB. I suspect it's a date formatting issue.

Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql) can help you with logging the queries that hit the database:

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
Select * from [Table] where StartDate between '06/13/2016' and '10/13/2016'
```

The above query fetches records between months 06 and 10.   Make sure that string in the `data variable` is in the above format.  Also the column type in the database is `date`.

Check and remove special characters, if any.

Mark this as answer if you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your select query. I have changed one of your select variable because it ambiguous for the Date datatype.

```
void FilterDBbtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();

        conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);


        //string data = "SELECT `Date`, `Process`, `Actual`, `Target` FROM `database` WHERE `Date` BETWEEN '"+this.fromDatePicker.Value+"' AND  '"+this.toDatePicker.Value+"' order by `Date` desc";

        //Changed query for getting data from DB according to the date 
        string data = "SELECT CreatedDate, Process, Actual, Target FROM database WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CreatedDate,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '"+this.fromDatePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"' AND  '"+this.toDatePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"' order by CreatedDate desc";


        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(data, conn);


        cmd.Connection.Open();

        try
        {

        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;            
        DataSet dt = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
        bsource.DataSource = dt;
        mondeDataTable.DataSource = dt.Tables[0];
        sda.Update(dt);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }


        cmd.Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code, i tried it but still i got error of "Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime". hope you can still help me with this.

Comment: may be this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754822/unable-to-convert-mysql-date-time-value-to-system-datetime

Comment: Use "DATE_FORMAT(CreatedDate,'%Y-%m-%d')" insetad of "Convert(varchar(10),CreatedDate,120)". I have given solution according to SQL server so I have changed the code. I hope it resolve your problem.

Comment: @dann11: Have you tried the solution again. I have changed the code accrding to MySql .