# Get value of Timestamp field from database and store in a string

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I am working on a project where I am getting values from a series of unknown of database schemas, i.e. the user can enter any database connection details and my program will retrieve the data so I am not going to know the type of tables used and what's stored in them.

At the moment when I try and get the values and store them all in a string so they can be written to a file, but one of the fields I am testing on has a Timestamp value and when I try to store this in the string variable I get the error `Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime`, I've tried saying `.toString()` but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Below is the code I am using to retrieve the data

```
using (ConnectMySQLDB db = new ConnectMySQLDB(databaseSettings))
{
   string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}.{1}", database, table);
   using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, db.conn))
   {
      using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
         while (reader.Read())
         {
            fieldsAndValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (string field in fields)
            {
               fieldsAndValues.Add(field, reader.GetString(field));

            }
            rows.Add(fieldsAndValues);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934844/unable-to-convert-mysql-date-time-value-to-system-datetime
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754822/unable-to-convert-mysql-date-time-value-to-system-datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934844/unable-to-convert-mysql-date-time-value-to-system-datetime)

Looks like they use different formats for storing time.  Hope this solves your issue.