# MySql.Data.Types.MySqlConversionException RDLC Reports

Tags: c#, report

i am trying to create Reports from two Range of dates using Report viewer, Now when i run the program, it triggers this Exception

```
An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.Types.MySqlConversionException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime
```

And i see it inside the Designer. on this Line.

```
public virtual int Fill(NewAppointmentDataset.final_appointmentsDataTable dataTable, System.DateTime FROM, System.DateTime TO) {
    this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[0];
    this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[0].Value = ((System.DateTime)(FROM));
    this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[1].Value = ((System.DateTime)(TO));
    if ((this.ClearBeforeFill == true)) {
        dataTable.Clear();
    }
    int returnValue = this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
    return returnValue;
}
```

And in the main Form , I do something like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.final_appointmentsTableAdapter.Fill(this.NewAppointmentDataset.final_appointments, DateTime.Parse(dtFrom.Text), DateTime.Parse(dtTo.Text));
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

Whats Wrong? Like why am i getting this Exception Error??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934844/unable-to-convert-mysql-date-time-value-to-system-datetime)

Comment: This comes up a lot - please search SO before posting your question

Comment: @bugFinder , I saw others before talking about the error here :)

Comment: Well you havent given any info to suggest as such and so what makes your case different to the like 20 other questions of the same error

Comment: @BugFinder, Date format? i have set the other value to True. and its still acting up

Comment: @BugFinder, i said i was using a Report viewer .4